# Poor man's manner of conducting Agile Scrum/kanban/lean/XP software development philosophies/practices while remotely working online over the internet

Tags: agile, kanban, lean, safe, extreme-programming

Due to the covid-19 pandemic, I and my colleagues work remotely from home. I'm trying to document user stories. Unfortunately, since we work remotely from home, I cannot sit next to my colleagues with some kind "Kanban" black board, and a bunch of "user story" post-it notes. Also, my company will not pay extra for Jira's Kanban features. Is there some kind of poor man's Agile Scrum/kanban/lean/XP internet online software tool?

Or is there some kind of "ad hoc" way of putting "user stories", and the corresponding progression/status of said "user stories" on the internet in order to share it with my colleagues?

Comment: Software requests are generally off-topic. Consider rewording to focus on the issue/goal rather than the software request.

Comment: There are lots of software options, for example: [trello.com](http://trello.com), [miro.com](http://miro.com), [clickup.com](http://clickup.com)

Comment: As stated, this question is about to be closed, unless we find a way to restructure it (assuming we want to). Asked this in https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/884/how-to-handle-a-off-topic-question-that-has-a-potentially-very-good-on-topic-q

Comment: Software questions are inherently opinion-based. You may be able to improve your question and ask it on Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the projects you are working on are small / medium Scrum projects.

Google spreadsheets or Excel Office 365 (to enable online collaboration) could be an alternatives.

You could google search for managing small/medium scrum projects using Google Spreadsheets templates(**free**) or MS Excel templates to be used with Office 365 for sharing(**paid**).

Here take look at one example of google spreadsheet template and Excel to start with:

- [Google Sheet Template for agile scrum projects](https://evenbytes.com/google-sheet-template-for-agile-scrum-projects-reporting-automations/)
- [Scrum Metrics – Excel Template, Do watch corresponding videos on that page](https://agiledigest.com/product/scrummetricstemplate/)

Answer (score 1):

### Open source software for Scrum/Kanban

Here are two open source options for software project manangement using Scrum/Kanban.

1. [Tuleap ALM](https://www.tuleap.org/explore/): See the Explore Tuleap Community Edition section for more details.
2. [Taiga on-premise self-managed](https://www.taiga.io/onpremise)

However:

- You need to pay for the hosting provider.
- You need in-house skills to install, operate and maintain these software.